# causal graph - counting the number of backdoor paths in a DAG

Tags: causality, dag, causal-diagram

I am following "[A Crash Course in Causality: Inferring Causal Effects from Observational Data](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crash-course-in-causality)" on Coursera.

I am struggling at correctly identifying backdoor paths in causal graphs (or DAG for Directed Acyclic Graph).

**Example #1 :**

The following DAG is given in example in week $2$'s video on the "backdoor path criterion".
[image]

The course states that there are $3$ backdoor paths from $A$ to $Y,$ but I see $4$ of them:

\begin{align*}
&A \leftarrow W \leftarrow Z \leftarrow V \to Y\\
&A \leftarrow W \to M \to Y\\
&A \leftarrow Z \leftarrow V \to Y\\
&A \leftarrow Z \to W \to M \to Y \quad (\text{not pointed out})
\end{align*}

**Example #2 :**

In the same week quiz, we are asked to count the number of backdoor paths on this DAG:

[image]

Apparently, there is only $1$ but once again I see more of them (I count $2$ of them):

\begin{align*}
&G \to A \to B\\
&G \leftarrow E \leftarrow D \to A \to B
\end{align*}

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Example 1, you are correct. $A\leftarrow Z\to W\to M\to Y$ is a valid backdoor path with no colliders in it (which would stop the backdoor path from being a problem).

In Example 2, you are incorrect. The definition of a backdoor path implies that the first arrow has to go *into* $G$ (in this case), or it's not a backdoor path. Only $G\leftarrow E\leftarrow D\to A\to B$ satisfies that criterion.

Comment: Thank you clarifying things out! I was indeed missing something on the definition of a backdoor path: that path must "go into" the treatment and not "go from" it (and influence the outcome).

Comment: @Tanguy Right, but that does only go for the first arrow. As long as you don't have a collider on the path, like this: $A\to B\leftarrow C,$ which blocks data flow from $A$ to $C$ unless you condition on $B,$ then the arrow direction is unimportant after that first arrow. You're welcome for the help!

Comment: OK, though I understand that a path with a collider can still be counted as a backdoor path (even though it is blocked unless the collider is conditioned on).

Comment: Perhaps. At that point, it's more semantics. The crucial thing to know is whether you need to condition on various variables.

Comment: I think you're right, by the way: backdoor paths can be blocked or not. The first arrow into the treatment is the critical piece.

Comment: I agree with @Adrian. However to his information I would add that the path G→A→B is rather a front door path.

Comment: @AshaChoudhary Are you sure? I've rather thought about frontdoor paths as going straight from cause to effect, with no other connections to the intermediate variable. The fact that $D\to A$ means it doesn't qualify as frontdoor path, unless I'm mistaken.